# UICollectionViewCells and Buttons

Tags: ios, ios6, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've been trying to get my `UICollectionView` to respond differently to single and double taps but all the answers I have found seem to suggest this is not really feasible because the single taps get recognised first.  It works on really slow taps, but anything faster always initiates the default gesture recogniser (if anybody has got this to work I would love to know)...

So anyway, I have now resorted to putting buttons in my `UICollectionViewCell` (which has it's own class and NIB file).

The question is this:

What is considered the best way to use the button in the `UIViewController` of the collectionView?

I currently have a *protocol* in the header of my subclass of `UICollectionViewCell` and have declared my viewController as the *delegate* and implemented the required protocol functions.

In `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` I set the VC as the delegate of the cell.

It all works but it seems a bit long-winded, and maybe not a great way of doing this.

The other way I was thinking of was instead of using delegates to simply call `addTarget:Action:` on the property of the `UICollectionViewCell` in  `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`.

This seems simpler but the delegate pattern looks to me like the better fit.

Any and all advice on which would be better, why, and any more appropriate alternatives welcomed!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing the right think using the delegation pattern. The ultimate responsible object for any action of your views is the viewController who's displaying those views. Therefore, using it as the delegate for you cell's protocol is just right.

Comment: Gianluca, thanks.  I was torn between this method and just adding the action to the button in 'collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:'.  Any thought on which would be better... or Why?

Comment: You could have just put the button's action in the viewController's code but that would have been poor object-oriented code. Your viewController doesn't need to know how the action is triggered: it might have been a button, a gesture recogniser, an API call to the cell itself from some other object. It doesn't matter. Your viewController should only care about handling the action that the cell tells him has occurred. So, it's just good OOP practice and makes your code more reusable.

Comment: Thanks, it is so obvious when you put it like that.

Answer (score -1):

create a custom subview of `UICollectionViewCell` and place your button in the `initWithFrame` method. Declare the button to be public so you can use it later in your `uicollectionviewcontroller` or `uicollectionview` if creating programmatically.

Comment: Meenakshi, thanks for the quick answer but it doesn't make sense to me...  Doesn't mean you are wrong, I just don't get it.